# How can i get my input field focused after 1 sec in Iphone device?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get my field autoFocus after few seconds but not getting in `Iphone device`.

I set autofocus to true after 1 sec using setTimeout method in componentDidMount method.

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({
      autofocus: true
    })
   }, 1000);
}
```

`<input autoFocus={this.state.autoFocus}  />`

I expect the output as i load the page input field should get focus after 1 sec.

Comment: You are setting timeout to 8s in your code.

Comment: sorry, i just changed it. its by mistake

Comment: The `autofocus` attribute only has an effect, if it is present when the page loads - you can not dynamically add it afterwards, and expect it to work then. Call the `focus` method of the input field instead.

Comment: that works fine in android device but not in iphone devices.

Comment: @misorude its working fine in android device but when it comes to ios input field getting focused but keyboard is not coming up? is there any sol for that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html),

> **When to Use Refs**
>
> There are a few good use cases for refs:
>
> 1. Managing focus, text selection, or media playback.
> 2. Triggering imperative animations.
> 3. Integrating with third-party DOM libraries.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
}

componentDidMount(){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    this.myRef.current.focus()
  },1000) //executes after 1 sec
}

<input type="text"  ref={this.myRef} />
```

**Note:** `componentDidMount` work in `mounting phase` only, when you refresh your component then your component don't go through `componentDidMount` function and you will not get focus here. For that you need some other lifecycle method like `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: its not working in iphone os its working only in android.

Comment: Try this - `ref={input => this.myRef = input }`.

Comment: @Mrityunjay No idea about that, you should edit your question and add `iphone` tag so that this question gets attention.

Answer (score 0):

you cant change autofocus dynamically, a solution can be to use ref and in your componentDidMount or anywhere else you like set the focus on the input like below

```js
import React, { Component, createRef } from 'react';

class MyInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.textInput = createRef();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.textInput.current.focus();
    }, 4000);
  }
  render() {
    return <input ref={this.textInput} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: its not working in iphone os its working only in android.